# OpenCV/JavaCV Android Face Detection Initialization

Tags: java, android, xml, opencv, javacv

I am working on a Face Detection Problem, I have working code that uses Androids FaceDetector to find the faces but I need to figure out a way to implement OpenCV/JavaCV functions to detect faces. This is not using a live camera, it uses a image from the gallery, I am able to retrieve that images path, but I cant seem to get the CvHaarClassifierCascade classifier, and CvMemStorage storage to initialized, if anyone cant point me in the right direction or provide some source code that initializes these variable correctly in Java.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this: Just provide an BufferedImage.

Alternatively load the original IplImage directly with the image path using cvLoadImage(..).

```
// provide an BufferedImage
BufferedImage image;

// Preload the opencv_objdetect module to work around a known bug.
Loader.load(opencv_objdetect.class);

// Path to the cascade file provided by opencv
String cascade = "../haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml"

CvHaarClassifierCascade cvCascade = new CvHaarClassifierCascade(cvLoad(cascade));

// create storage for face detection
CvMemStorage tempStorage = CvMemStorage.create();

// create IplImage from BufferedImage
IplImage original = IplImage.createFrom(image);

IplImage grayImage = null;

if (original.nChannels() >= 3) {
  // We need a grayscale image in order to do the recognition, so we
  // create a new image of the same size as the original one.
  grayImage = IplImage.create(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
                IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
  // We convert the original image to grayscale.
  cvCvtColor(original, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
} else {
  grayImage = original.clone();
}

// We detect the faces with some default params
CvSeq faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(grayImage, cvCascade,
            tempStorage, 1.1, 3,
            0;

// Get face rectangles
CvRect[] fArray = new CvRect[faces.total()];
for (int i = 0; i < faces.total(); i++) {
            fArray[i] = new CvRect(cvGetSeqElem(faces, i));
        }
// print them out
for(CvRect f: fArray){
   System.out.println("x: " + f.x() + "y: " + f.y() + "width: " + f.width() +  "height: " + f.height());
}

tempStorage.release();
```

Answer (score 1):

The class definitions are basically ports to Java of the original header files in C, plus the missing functionality exposed only by the C++ API of OpenCV. you can refer this link,it includes http://code.google.com/p/javacv/

and http://geekoverdose.wordpress.com/tag/opencv-javacv-android-haarcascade-face-detection/